# Button to direct users to different pages based on login role status

Tags: php, wordpress, function, button

I have the below code that is in my functions.php

```
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
//is there a user to check?
if (isset($user->roles) && is_array($user->roles)) {
    //check for subscribers
    if (in_array('free_user', $user->roles)) {
        // redirect them to another URL, in this case, the homepage 
        $redirect_to =  get_permalink(100);
    }else if (in_array('paid_user', $user->roles)) {
        // redirect them to another URL, in this case, the homepage 
        $redirect_to =  get_permalink(200);
    }else if (in_array('premium_user', $user->roles)) {
        // redirect them to another URL, in this case, the homepage 
        $redirect_to =  get_permalink(300);
    }
}

return $redirect_to;
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 1, 3 );
```

Now in my main page, I have a button that I would like the user to be able to click on the button and it will direct them to the different pages depending on their login role.

And perhaps to pop up a message to say "Please login first!" if user is not logged in at all

Any advise?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to different pages based on the user roles, please follow this code, it works for me

```
<?php 
    if(is_user_logged_in()){
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $roles = ( array ) $user->roles;
        if (in_array('free_user', $user->roles)) {
            $link = get_permalink(100);
        }else if (in_array('paid_user', $user->roles)) {
            $link = get_permalink(200);
        }else if (in_array('paid_user', $user->roles)) {
            $link = get_permalink(300);
        }else{
            $link = get_permalink(3);
        }
?>
        <button onclick="location.href ='<?php echo $link; ?>';">Try it</button>
<?php }else{ ?>
        <button onclick="alert('Please login first!')">Try it</button>
<?php } ?>
```